# Using SortBy on a list of a list of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have quite a typical physics problem at hand, I want the eigenvalues and -vectors of a Hamiltonian matrix. I have a parameter s, which I vary in 1000 steps and for each step I want my H matrix to be diagonalized and then sort for the eigenvalues. For that purpose I use something like

```
Eigs = {};
Do[
  (* defining stuff *)
  H = (* setting matrix *);
  Eigs = Append[H, Eigensystem[H]]
,
  {s ,start, stop, (stop-start)/1000}]
```

Now I have an array `Eigs`, which has three indices:

```
Eigs[[s, i, j]]
```

where `i` specifies the i-th `{Eigenvalues[H][[i]], Eigenvectors[H][[i]]}` and `j = 1` gives the eigenvalue, while `j= 2` gives the eigenvector. Fixing `i` and setting `j = 2`, I get the i-th energyband in `s`, which I want to plot. Now I want to sort these bands for their energy, which I want to do by just summing over all values of a band to get a number and then sort the pairs `{Eigenvalues[H][[i]], Eigenvectors[H][[i]]}` according to these numbers, highest first.

My problem now is, that I have no idea how to use `SortBy` in this situation! If I had, for example, the same situation without the eigenvectors, so

```
Eigs = {};

Do[
  (* defining stuff *)
  H = (* setting matrix *);
  Eigs = Append[H, Eigenvalues[H]]
, 
  {s, start, stop, (stop-start)/1000}]
```

Then I only have `Eigs[[s, i]]`, which I can sort by

```
sortedEigs = Transpose[SortBy[Transpose[Eigs], Total[#] &]]
```

But I want to sort the eigenvectors as well, so my guess was something like

```
sortedEigs = Transpose[SortBy[Transpose[Eigs], Total[Eigs[[All, #, 1]]] &]]
```

but that does not work. In fact it seems to me, that I can't use the array Eigs itself in the second argument of `SortBy`.

I hope it is kind of clear, what I want to do and what my problem is and that someone can help me with that!

Comment: I assume you mean `Eigs = Append[Eigs, …]` instead of `Eigs = Append[H, …]`? As a side-note, you might want to use `Eigs = Table[…;Eigensystem[H], {s, …}]` in that case for increased readability & performance.

Comment: Yes, your right! Sorry, mixed them up. Thank you for the advice!